# VBS and XPATH to process multiple XML files

Tags: xml, vbscript

this script seaches thru Windows subfolders for XML files. The loop should load the XML file and do an operation then pass to the next XML file, etc.

This line is not being interpreted the way i hoped :

```
If oXML.load(objFile.name) Then
WScript.Echo "XML file loaded"
```

What is the proper way to write this code ?

Here is the complete script.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\test_env"

set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
oXML.async = "false"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
Wscript.Echo

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "XML" Then
               Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
               Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
               ' LOAD THE XML FILE
               If oXML.load(objFile.name) Then
               WScript.Echo "XML loaded"
               Else WScript.Echo "XML not loaded"
              End If
            End If
        Next
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The .load method needs the full path to the .xml file, so change

```
If oXML.load(objFile.name) Then
```

to

```
If oXML.load(objFile.Path) Then
```

It may be a good idea to look at `.parseError.reason` in case of failure.